Selenium XPATH for Google general search - how to improve results
I wrote a Python program to run a Google search for each company name in an Excel sheet. However, I get a lot more search results when manually searching the company names up on google.
I suspect it's related to my XPATH, yet my knowledge with Selenium and HTML is very limited. I would appreciate it if you could shed some light on how to increase the search results returned by the program.
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\company_names.xlsx')
company_names = df['company_name'].tolist()
#company_names = df['company_name'].replace(' ', '+')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

def search_and_snap(company_name):
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    query = company_name + 'news'
    search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q')
    search_box.send_keys(query + Keys.RETURN)
    sleep(5)
    print(f'Searching for {company_name} + 'news')
    links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="g"]//a')

    print(f'Found {len(links)} links for {company_name}')
    results = []
    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute('href')
        if href and href.startswith('http'):
            print(href)
            results.append(href)

for company_name in company_names:
    search_and_snap(company_name)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 5))

driver.quit()

